# Javascript: Calling a function with argument "e"

Tags: javascript, event-handling, arguments

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
        myGameArea.x = e.pageX;
        myGameArea.y = e.pageY;
    })
```

What I don't understand is what the argument "e" is doing and how it is relevant, or what it's value is. If anyone needs me to link the entire piece of code ("it's a relatively small piece of code, one that runs a movable object"). I know that the question may not be well presented or that the answer may be obvious but I can't wrap my head around it well enough to phrase my question better. Also, google was no help. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Some more examples from the code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
        myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    })
```

and

```
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
        myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false; 
    })
```

Comment: It's mousemove event object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addEventListener` method takes two parameters. One is the event name. The second is a callback function. You're actually passing an entire function to `addEventListener` that will be called at a later time.

`addEventListener` will hold on to that method. When an event is triggered, `addEventListener` will call your callback method. When your callback is called, the caller will pass an object representing the event. It allows you to get the details of the event inside your callback method.

Comment: Interesting... so the parameter passed was presumably the event object? Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @HuzaifahFarooq - That's exactly what it is. You should also keep in mind that it doesn't matter what you name the variable in your callback (some people use `e`, others use `event`).

Answer (score 1):

It is the event object. A parameter implicitly passed into the event listener function so that you can grab properties from the event that occurred. For example, the x,y coordinates of the mouse, the `preventDefault` method, the event target origin, etc.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) for more details on what the event object has, and how it's bound to the function event.

Comment: Ah, the event object! Yes, I do know that, but shouldn't the parameter passed be "event" not "e"?

Comment: Nah, you can name it whatever you like, but `e` and `event` are typically the go to parameter names